# Начало изучения OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть пару вопросов, как мне кажется, стандартных при старте изучения OpenGl.

1. Расскажите подробнее про версии (как мне известно, их 4), в чем их различие, существенное ли оно и т.д. и т.п.
2. Подскажите пожалуйста хорошую книгу или видеоуроки без литья воды и заумных выпендрежей.

Comment: Дискриманация новичков и ди-би-лизм! Нормальный вопрос! Помогите лучше!

Comment: Если бы ещё в ответах linux-версия была

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы уже научились программировать в windows, то вам [сюда](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/) - это уже чистый (без дополнений) opengl под windows.
А книги по opengl почти все одинаковые (ищите их на ozon.ru), все описывают его стандарт (но хвалят все opengl red book и [вот эту](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=1&pvalue=OpenGL+%CF%F0%EE%F4%E5%F1%F1%E8%EE%ED%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%E5+%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5+%F2%F0%E5%F5%EC%E5%F0%ED%EE%E9+%E3%F0%E0%F4%E8%EA%E8+%ED%E0+C%2B%2B&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)).

**Обновление**

Весь opengl - это набор функций, что-то убирают, что-то добавляют отсюда, и версии разные. Насчет крайсиса я смотрел сравнивающую directx и opengl демку, разницы при рендеринге нет http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HC3JGG6xHN8

Comment: А чем будет отличаться 1 версия opengl от четвертой, можно ли написать "крайзис" на первом opengl?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Получается, что отрисовка 10 тысяч треугольников в opengl 1, по скорости будет такая же, как и в opengl 4, и разницы между версиями opengl, кроме внедрения новых функций и стиля кода, нет?

Comment: Это от ресурсов машины зависит только и реализации opengl драйвера.

Comment: @perfect спасибо тебе, Человек!